# NSMenuItem enabled state, dynamic naming and target action

Tags: cocoa, menuitem

I am having a problem with my app's menu. I want a few items in the menu to be greyed out depending on some `BOOL` variables.

Also, I want some of my menu items to get names depending on some `BOOL` variables and thereby execute different functions depending on what the menu item name is. Is this possible? As using Interface Builder you can link a menu item to one IBAction method. please tell me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [NSMenuValidation protocol](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

You implement -validateMenuItem:, which is used to determine whether a menu item should be enabled or disabled.  It's called for each menu item just before a menu is popped up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can set a menu item's enabled state and its title programmatically; see the NSMenuItem documentation. Remember to use `NSLocalizedString` when obtaining the title format.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question; you don't need to use Interface Builder to hook up Target/action for Menu items.

You can use code such as this:

```
NSMenuItem *menuItem; // Set this to your menu item.
// Set the target to an instance of a class which contains the action method.
[menuItem setTarget:targetClass]; 
// Set the action to the (IBAction) method to call.
[menuItem setAction:NSSelectorFromString(@"actionMethod")];
```

Comment: Er, `target` should generally be an instance, not a class. It can be a class, but that's not usually what you want. (Also, you forgot a ‘`)`’.)

Comment: Shorthand: @selector(actionMethod:)